# AutoCompleteExtender list width not working

Tags: list, width, autocompleteextender

I have a custom control with AutoCompleteExtender and i used the "onListPopulated" to set the list width. Im using more than one ref for this custom control in my page. My Problem is :
the width is not setting for all references. It setting only for the last ref. How can i fix it.

Thank in Advance.